# Solr boost query sort by whether result is boosted then by another field

Tags: sorting, search, solr, lucene

I'm using Solr to run a query on one of our cores.  Suppose my documents have two fields: ID, and Name.  I also have a separate list of IDs I'm grabbing from a database and passing into the query to boost certain results.

If the document gets returned in the query and the ID is in the list it goes to the top of the results, and if it gets returned in the query and the ID is not in the list then it goes below those that are in the list.  The former is from the "boost".  My query is something like this -
http://mysolrserver:8983/solr/MyCore/MyQueryHandler?q=Smith&start=0&rows=25&bq=Id%3a(36+OR+76+OR+90+OR+224+OR+391)

I am able to get the boost query working but I need the boosted results to be in alphabetical order by name, then the non boosted results under that also in alphabetical order by name. I need to know what to user for the &sort= parameter.
&sort=score%20desc,Name+asc does not work.
I've looked over a lot of documentation, but I still don't know if this even possible.  Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Solr version is 6.0.1.  I am actually using SolrNet to interface with Solr, but I think I can figure out the SolrNet part if I know what the url's &sort= parameter value needs to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, by doing away with the boost query. I added a sort query using the "exists" function and passing it a sub-query for the ID.  The exists returns a boolean value to sort on, then I added the name as a second sort.  It works perfect!!
The URL looks like this:

```
http://mysolrserver:8983/solr/MyCore/MyQueryHandler?q=Smith&start=0&rows=25&sort=exists(query({!v=%27Id:(36+OR+76+OR+90+OR+224+OR+391)%27}))%20DESC,%20Name%20ASC
```

Comment: Mindful solution using standart query parser. It even sorts the boosted records respecting second sort field.

Answer (score 0):

The closest match to your requirement is the query elevation component[1] .
In your particular case I would first sort my Ids according to my requirements ( sorting them by name for example), then maintain them in the elevate.xml.

At query time you can use the "forceElevation" parameter to force the elevation and then sort the remaining results by name.

[1] https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+Query+Elevation+Component

Comment: Thanks for your response, but creating the document would not work because the ID's would be dynamic.